# Error when sending function as argument, sometimes

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

The error is `'GLHandler::handleKeys': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`
four times, on different functions.

I am trying to make a wrapper class for initialising glut, to make things cleaner.

The error appears on 4 lines all for the same reason, though I'm not sure why.

*All of these are setting callbacks*

Inside initGlut function:

```
glutKeyboardFunc(this->handleKeys); 
glutDisplayFunc(this->render);
glutTimerFunc(1000 / SCREEN_FPS, this->runMainLoop, 0);
```

Inside `runMainLoop` function

```
glutTimerFunc(1000 / this->SCREEN_FPS, this->runMainLoop, val);
```

The errors being thrown here *do not exist* when called identically from inside main which leads me to believe something is wrong with the class, but I can't see it.

Comment: What is the exact error? Are you seeing this error when compiling or at runtime?

Comment: I have added it, at compile

Comment: You need to either use a free function or a static member function as a callback.

Comment: I see, is there a particular reason for that limitation?

Comment: `this->handleKeys`,  `this->render` and `this->runMainLoop` are class methods rather than functions. The callback has to be a function (or a static method).

Comment: Sure, I understand what you said, but could you explain why that's the case, I don't see how that would be useful

Comment: For a free or static function the signature is whatever you say it is, like `int foo(int, double);`. Id that was a member function the signature would actually be `int foo(class*, int, double);` where `class*` is your *this* pointer. The call back can't supply that this pointer so it cannot call the member function.

Comment: This explains it in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749617/how-to-use-a-c-member-function-as-the-callback-function-for-a-c-framework but I'm not sure it's really a duplicate or your problem since in that particular situation there's a parameter to the callback that could be used to store the this pointer. Glut is not quite so accommodating. :(

Comment: ok thanks for all of the help :)

Comment: I will say actually, it does make sense that you cant have instances of an update, render, or keyinput function, as it is possible for only one to exist at a time. I suppose they could have used singletons instead.

Comment: Yeah, I've used a singleton before as a dispatcher that class instances register with to get the callbacks.

Comment: actually, that sounds like a good idea, I'll give it a test :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this->handleKeys`, `this->render` and `this->runMainLoop` are class methods rather than functions. The callback has to be a function or a static method.

e.g. See [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html) (and see also [*freeglut* Application Programming Interface](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php)):

> `glutDisplayFunc` sets the display callback for the current window.
>
> Usage
>
> ```
> void glutDisplayFunc(void (*func)(void));
> ```

Note, the method of a class can only be called by an object of the class. The pointer to an `method` is not sufficient. You can imagine the method of a class, as a function where the first parameter is the pointer to an object of the class.

If there is a class

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    void render(void);
};
```

Then a pointer to the method `render` can be get by `&Foo::render`. But the type of the pointer is `void(Foo::*)(void)` rather than `void(*)(void)`